# Handling services and sending data across activities

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to start a service from one activity to make an api call and obtain its result in another activity. I use a BroadcastReceiver to receive the data but how do I make sure that the activity is created and the receiver is attached before sending the broadcast from the service. Is there something wrong with the way that I'm designing this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: To simply this, I'm starting a 3 second animation when the app is called. I do not want to waste that time and so I'm trying to get data from network and then display it on the activity called after the animation ends. I assumed IntentService would be the way to go but if its not please suggest me how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Sticky Events](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/) from [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) library. Basically it will cache your data in memory before broadcasting events. The data can be delivered to subscribers. Thus, you don’t need any special logic to consider already available data.

First you need to declare a class to hold data which you get from network.

```
public class MyDataEvent {
    String token;
    // Write more properties here
}
```

In the service, after getting the data from network, post event which contains data to subscribers.

```
MyDataEvent data = new MyDataEvent();
data.token = "123456789abcxyz";
EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(data);
```

In activity which you want to receive the data

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
}

// UI updates must run on MainThread
@Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMyDataEvent(MyDataEvent data) {   
    // Process the data here
    Log.i("TAG", data.token);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);    
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: `Post an event from any part of your code. All currently registered subscribers matching the event type will receive it.` The problem is I'm receiving the response before the EventBus can be registered.

Comment: No worry. With sticky event, your response will be cached. Whenever the activity register to event, it will receive the response immediately.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to be firing. I used the code you posted above and it only fires if the postSticky runs after the EventBus has registered. Otherwise it just doesn't fire

Comment: I'll read the docs and figure it out. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Glad to hear that. Happy coding :)